Expo notifications crash on Click action on Development Client
Hi Iam facing issue with notification click on Android, iam using expo backend server for trigger. Iam getting notifications as expected but onlick actions its getting crashed .It is working as expected in Expo Go only on Develop client iam getting crash and i see no logs of any sort and i integrated crashylitics to see report i got abort error not specific error please anyone help
Iam using expo 50
I receive notification on Foreground and also background as expected but it is getting crashed on click and same code is working fine with Expo go
I use Expo 50
